# How to create SSL for website without domain name using certbot?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, lamp, certbot

I have a website hosted on my Ubuntu LAMP server having static public IP (example: 10.11.12.13).

I want to add SSL certificate to this. I am following this tutorial link: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntu-18

[image]

It is not clear whether it is mandatory to have domain name or whether IP address is sufficient?

Comment: *"static public IP (example: 10.11.12.13)"* - this example is not a public IP address but reserved for internal use - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network. Apart from that LE does not issue certificates for IP addresses, only for domains,

Answer (score 1):

You can create a self signed SSL snakeoil certificate with just an IP address however this will still show a warning in chrome when a client tries to access your website via HTTPS as you are not a credible authority. However despite the warning in chrome network traffic will still be encrypted via HTTPS.

Certbot issues SSL certificates from a credible authority known as R3 (Let's Encrypt) so chrome will not show a warning message when a client tries to access your website via HTTPS. You need a domain name if you want R3 (Let's Encrypt) to issue you an SSL certificate.

Comment: since you seem to know about this stuff, i have deployed my site locally and the use a ddns service that points to my ip, just so i can avoid having to purchase a domain. 
So basically, if i want to have https is having a domain necessary ?